# Distribute my turtles of patches except ones that are part of a set

Tags: netlogo, patch

So in this project a obstacle is created with:

```
  set obstacle patches with [ abs(pxcor) < 15 and abs(pycor) < 15 ]
  crt 1 [ set size 30 set shape "square" set color gray set heading 0 ]
```

Now I want to distribute my patches around the obstacle, but I can't figure out how to place them anywhere but on the obstacle. So I'm looking for something like (but this gives a syntax error):

```
 move-to one-of patches with [ patch not obstacle and not any? turtles-here ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `move-to one-of patches with [ not member? self obstacle and not any? turtles-here ]`. You are already telling NetLogo you want to test the `patches` by specifying `patches with`, you don't need to repeat that for the obstacle test.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in: "NOT expected input to be a TRUE/FALSE but got the agentset (agentset, 841 patches) instead."

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood how you create the obstacle - I had thought it was a patch attribute but it's actually a patch-set. Have edited my answer.